# C# SQL server connection

Tags: c#, sql

HI 
As a daily check I have to check the SQL connection to all our servers. At the moment this is done by manually logging on through SQL server managment studio. I was just wondering if this can be coded in C# so that I can run it first thing in a morning and its checks each server and the instance for a valid SQL connection and reports back to say if the connection is live or not.

Thanks Andy

Comment: Yes it can.  Can you write code?

Comment: Sorry should of said my C# is very limited. I can probably to get a hello world together and thats about it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little console app example that will cycle through a list of connections and attempt to connect to each, reporting success or failure.  Ideally you'd perhaps want to extend this to read in a list of [connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com) from a file, but this should hopefully get you started.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

namespace SQLServerChecker
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Use a dictionary to associate a friendly name with each connection string.
            IDictionary<string, string> connectionStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            connectionStrings.Add("Sales Database", "< connection string >");
            connectionStrings.Add("QA Database", "< connection string >");

            foreach (string databaseName in connectionStrings.Keys)
            {
                try
                {
                    string connectionString = connectionStrings[databaseName];

                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        Console.WriteLine("Connected to {0}", databaseName);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Handle the connection failure.
                    Console.WriteLine("FAILED to connect to {0} - {1}", databaseName, ex.Message);
                }
            }

            // Wait for a keypress to stop the console closing.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to finish.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) Class. It includes a basic sample. Just put a loop around that sample to connect to each server, and if any server fails to connect it throws an exception.

Then just set it up as a scheduled task in Windows.

A nice way to report the status might be with an email, which can easily be sent out with [SmtpClient.Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx) (the link has a nice simple sample.

Answer (score 2):

Why c#? You could make a simple batch file that does this using the osql command.

```
osql -S servername\dbname -E -Q "select 'itworks'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at this method:

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()
```

It gives you a list of SQL servers available on the network.

Answer (score -1):

You know, they make monitoring tools that let you know if your sql server goes down . . .